# How can I fix an Opencart 3 page loading error?

Tags: opencart

The following problem sometimes occurs when the page loads and also on the admin page. The error is not permanent and will disappear after the page is refreshed. What could be the problem and how could I fix it?

This is an error message:

> Warning: fopen(/web/htdocs4/wallartdecorhu/home/www/system/storage/cache/cache.store.1604651378): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /web/htdocs4/wallartdecorhu/home/www/system/library/cache/file.php on line 28Warning: flock() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /web/htdocs4/wallartdecorhu/home/www/system/library/cache/file.php on line 30Warning: filesize(): stat failed for /web/htdocs4/wallartdecorhu/home/www/system/storage/cache/cache.store.1604651378 in /web/htdocs4/wallartdecorhu/home/www/system/library/cache/file.php on line 32Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /web/htdocs4/wallartdecorhu/home/www/system/library/cache/file.php on line 32Warning: flock() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /web/htdocs4/wallartdecorhu/home/www/system/library/cache/file.php on line 34Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /web/htdocs4/wallartdecorhu/home/www/system/library/cache/file.php on line 36

Comment: Which version of **Opencart 3** are you using?

Comment: 3.0.2.0 version

Answer (score 0):

Keep a backup of `system/library/cache/file.php` and then download `system/library/cache/file.php` from https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/library/cache/file.php and replace the old one.

Comment: If your issue is resolved, please accept the answer as the solution

Comment: what else can you suggest?